# Select first element for one sublist in a 2d list python

Tags: python-3.x

```
QUAKE_DATA = [ 
    ['2017-11-16T18:42:11.676Z', '61.7647', '-153.9615', '0.8', '2.1', 'ml', 
     '', '', '', '0.64', 'ak', 'ak17253456', 
     '2017-11-16T18:58:24.707Z', '156km NNW of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska', 'earthquake', 
     '', '0.2', '', '', 'automatic', 'ak', 'ak'],
    ['2017-11-16T18:35:00.940Z', '34.1638333', '-116.4253333', '10.17', '1.76', 'ml', 
     '58', '33', '0.03663', '0.17', 'ci', 'ci37812975', 
     '2017-11-16T19:14:13.440Z', '6km N of Yucca Valley, CA', 'earthquake', 
     '0.14', '0.32', '0.18', '50', 'reviewed', 'ci', 'ci'], 
    ['2017-11-16T18:06:15.460Z', '34.0181667', '-116.862', '17.3', '0.9', 'ml', 
     '23', '108', '0.04811', '0.12', 'ci', 'ci37812967', 
     '2017-11-16T19:23:12.335Z', '10km N of Banning, CA', 'earthquake', 
     '0.23', '0.61', '0.068', '13', 'reviewed', 'ci', 'ci'], 
    ['2017-11-16T17:59:31.810Z', '34.1671667', '-116.4225', '10.6', '1.08', 'ml', 
     '33', '61', '0.03261', '0.17', 'ci', 'ci37812951', 
     '2017-11-16T18:57:01.554Z', '6km N of Yucca Valley, CA', 'earthquake', 
     '0.25', '0.37', '0.169', '13', 'reviewed', 'ci', 'ci'],
     ['2017-11-16T17:47:50.270Z', '37.7361679', '-122.1466675', '4.09', '1.52', 'md', 
      '12', '126', '0.0248', '0.04', 'nc', 'nc72925680', 
      '2017-11-16T18:34:02.533Z', '1km NNE of San Leandro, California', 'earthquake',
      '0.25', '0.29', '0.13', '8', 'automatic', 'nc', 'nc'], 
     ['2017-11-16T17:44:51.030Z', '37.5636673', '-118.8346634', '1.8', '1.66', 'md', 
      '16', '196', '0.02668', '0.04', 'nc', 'nc72925675', 
      '2017-11-16T18:23:03.511Z', '15km SE of Mammoth Lakes, California', 'earthquake', 
      '0.63', '0.43', '0.25', '13', 'automatic', 'nc', 'nc'], 
     ['2017-11-16T17:34:22.310Z', '33.9796667', '-118.782', '14.78', '2.47', 'ml', 
      '41', '97', '0.06482', '0.25', 'ci', 'ci37812839', 
      '2017-11-16T19:11:53.824Z', '4km SE of Malibu, CA', 'earthquake', 
      '0.36', '0.68', '0.13', '94', 'reviewed', 'ci', 'ci']
   ]

for data in QUAKE_DATA:
    print (data[0])
```

result I am getting:

```
2017-11-16T18:42:11.676Z
2017-11-16T18:35:00.940Z
2017-11-16T18:06:15.460Z
2017-11-16T17:59:31.810Z
2017-11-16T17:47:50.270Z
2017-11-16T17:44:51.030Z
2017-11-16T17:34:22.310Z
```

Comment: What is the intended result? This is impossible to answer as it is as we don't know what you want! "Why isn't this code working?" is not a valid question here.

Comment: The intended result is the '2017-11-16T18:42:11.676Z' and not every single first element! I am trying to select the first element from the first sublist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first element from the first sub-list, just take the first sub-list with:

```
QUAKE_DATA[0]
```

and then take the first element from that sub-list by indexing again:

```
QUAKE_DATA[0][0]
```

Simple as that, giving:

```
'2017-11-16T18:42:11.676Z'
```

---

There is no need for a `for-loop` as you just want to get one element which you can index directly. As it is, you are looping through *every* list in `QUAKE_DATA` and printing the first item from that list.